# ORA-29532: Java call terminated by uncaught Java exception- 2005-2008 migration error

Tags: java, sql, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, runtime-error

I am using a C# application which will use both oracle and SQl 2005 for db connection. Recently we are migrating our SQL Server 2005 to Sql 2008. When i try to import my table to sql database using the dot net application i am getting the following error.

---

```
Java call terminated by uncaught Java exception: java.util.MissingResourceException: 
Can't find bundle for base name com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerResource, locale en_US

ORA-29532: Java call terminated by uncaught Java exception: java.util.MissingResourceException: 
Can't find bundle for base name com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerResource, locale en_US
ORA-06512: at "INTPL.DATASYNC_UTIL", line 8
ORA-06512: at line 1
```

[LAST_SAVED_ERR]

---

During the upgrade we also checked the following path ReportDBMetaDataUtil.java:

```
String password) throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException
    {
        Connection conn = null;
        switch (dbType)     //M.C
        {
            case DB_ORACLE:
                conn =getRemoteOracleDbConnection (dbURL, user, password);
                break;
            case DB_SQL_SERVER:
                Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");      //sql server 2005
                //Class.forName("com.microsoft.jdbc.sqlserver.SQLServerDriver");    
//sql server 2000

                conn =DriverManager.getConnection(dbURL, user, password);
                break;
        }   

        return conn;
}
```

Kindly give me some suggestion, or ideas of references to fix this issue.

Comment: Do you have the appropriate JDBC-driver in your classpath?

Comment: Sorry to give you only little information. I completely don't know how to start to fix this issue or where to check. Kinldy give me some him. Sorry for the trouble.

Comment: @Thorbjørn Ravn Andersen: Thanks a lot. Ya we have the exact jdbc driver in that location. Is there anything else to check ?

Comment: Is it available to the code throwing the exception?  It looks to me as the JVM in question complains about not having a "bundle".

Comment: The code for ReportDBMetaDataUtil.java is below:
http://hostcode.sourceforge.net/view/812

Comment: No.  Is the JDBC driver jar available to the JVM - not your IDE - actually executing the code?

Comment: Any steps to confirm that ?

Answer (score 1):

I'd start by writing idiomatic JDBC.  It's an interface-based API that's supposed to free you from writing exactly the kind of stuff that you posted.

You know you're doing it wrong the moment you see code that checks if it's Oracle or SQL Server.

Here's an example:

```
package persistence;

import java.sql.*;
import java.util.*;

/**
 * util.DatabaseUtils
 * User: Michael
 * Date: Aug 17, 2010
 * Time: 7:58:02 PM
 */
public class DatabaseUtils {
/*
    private static final String DEFAULT_DRIVER = "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver";
    private static final String DEFAULT_URL = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@host:1521:database";
    private static final String DEFAULT_USERNAME = "username";
    private static final String DEFAULT_PASSWORD = "password";
*/
/*
    private static final String DEFAULT_DRIVER = "org.postgresql.Driver";
    private static final String DEFAULT_URL = "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/party";
    private static final String DEFAULT_USERNAME = "pgsuper";
    private static final String DEFAULT_PASSWORD = "pgsuper";
*/
    private static final String DEFAULT_DRIVER = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
    private static final String DEFAULT_URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/party";
    private static final String DEFAULT_USERNAME = "party";
    private static final String DEFAULT_PASSWORD = "party";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        long begTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

        String driver = ((args.length > 0) ? args[0] : DEFAULT_DRIVER);
        String url = ((args.length > 1) ? args[1] : DEFAULT_URL);
        String username = ((args.length > 2) ? args[2] : DEFAULT_USERNAME);
        String password = ((args.length > 3) ? args[3] : DEFAULT_PASSWORD);

        Connection connection = null;

        try {
            connection = createConnection(driver, url, username, password);
            DatabaseMetaData meta = connection.getMetaData();
            System.out.println(meta.getDatabaseProductName());
            System.out.println(meta.getDatabaseProductVersion());

            String sqlQuery = "SELECT PERSON_ID, FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME FROM PERSON ORDER BY LAST_NAME";
            System.out.println("before insert: " + query(connection, sqlQuery, Collections.EMPTY_LIST));

            connection.setAutoCommit(false);
            String sqlUpdate = "INSERT INTO PERSON(FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME) VALUES(?,?)";
            List parameters = Arrays.asList("Foo", "Bar");
            int numRowsUpdated = update(connection, sqlUpdate, parameters);
            connection.commit();

            System.out.println("# rows inserted: " + numRowsUpdated);
            System.out.println("after insert: " + query(connection, sqlQuery, Collections.EMPTY_LIST));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            rollback(connection);
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            close(connection);
            long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            System.out.println("wall time: " + (endTime - begTime) + " ms");
        }
    }

    public static Connection createConnection(String driver, String url, String username, String password) throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {
        Class.forName(driver);
        if ((username == null) || (password == null) || (username.trim().length() == 0) || (password.trim().length() == 0)) {
            return DriverManager.getConnection(url);
        } else {
            return DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);
        }
    }

    public static void close(Connection connection) {
        try {
            if (connection != null) {
                connection.close();
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    public static void close(Statement st) {
        try {
            if (st != null) {
                st.close();
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void close(ResultSet rs) {
        try {
            if (rs != null) {
                rs.close();
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void rollback(Connection connection) {
        try {
            if (connection != null) {
                connection.rollback();
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static List<Map<String, Object>> map(ResultSet rs) throws SQLException {
        List<Map<String, Object>> results = new ArrayList<Map<String, Object>>();
        try {
            if (rs != null) {
                ResultSetMetaData meta = rs.getMetaData();
                int numColumns = meta.getColumnCount();
                while (rs.next()) {
                    Map<String, Object> row = new HashMap<String, Object>();
                    for (int i = 1; i <= numColumns; ++i) {
                        String name = meta.getColumnName(i);
                        Object value = rs.getObject(i);
                        row.put(name, value);
                    }
                    results.add(row);
                }
            }
        } finally {
            close(rs);
        }
        return results;
    }

    public static List<Map<String, Object>> query(Connection connection, String sql, List<Object> parameters) throws SQLException {
        List<Map<String, Object>> results = null;
        PreparedStatement ps = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;
        try {
            ps = connection.prepareStatement(sql);

            int i = 0;
            for (Object parameter : parameters) {
                ps.setObject(++i, parameter);
            }
            rs = ps.executeQuery();
            results = map(rs);
        } finally {
            close(rs);
            close(ps);
        }
        return results;
    }

    public static int update(Connection connection, String sql, List<Object> parameters) throws SQLException {
        int numRowsUpdated = 0;
        PreparedStatement ps = null;
        try {
            ps = connection.prepareStatement(sql);

            int i = 0;
            for (Object parameter : parameters) {
                ps.setObject(++i, parameter);
            }
            numRowsUpdated = ps.executeUpdate();
        } finally {
            close(ps);
        }
        return numRowsUpdated;
    }
}
```

Comment: Ya thanks a lot. But we were using the same code when we were using SQL 2005. We got the error only after migrating to SQL 2008. Is it because of some configuration problem ? Kindly suggest help me.

Comment: Migrating to 2008?  You're still five years behind.

Comment: This is how we have used in our program 
http://hostcode.sourceforge.net/view/812

I have searched in google, but no luck.
I am unable to find even a clue abt this problem.
Can u suggest me some steps to find the causes for this problem.